# PyQT5 GUI not working under MacOS Monterey

Tags: python, pyqt5, macos-monterey

I have recently switched to MacBook with M1 processor and macOS Monterey, and my application in PyQT5 stopped displaying images. All other features seems to work.

I had the same problem on previous Mac after upgrading to Big Sur. In that case adding
`os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'` solved the problem, but it didn't now.